# find DOM position of a <script> section

Tags: javascript, dom, position

I'm writing a little library that should be used by people who don't know anything about programming, and it should add "complex" html component with one or two javascript lines (like a form with some inputs and texts to insert email and other credentials).

It's possible to "self-identify" script position to add element to DOM in that position? I mean, for example, in a code like this

```
<div>
    <p> ... </p>
    <script>
         // my code is here
    </script>
    <a> ... </a>
    ...
</div>
```

I want to add an element in the position where script is written (son of div and after p), assuming that no element has specific id. Is it possibile?

Comment: This was just mentioned on the whatwg list in the "[whatwg] <script> features" thread. See http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2012-March/thread.html#35161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `document.write()` is the only way to do this.

You could abuse this to get the containing element though by creating an element with a unique ID and then accessing the `.parentNode` of this element.